# itunesconnect is not updating the build of my app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app on apple app store, recently I made some changes in it and updated it using Xcode build > archive > upload to app store. Itunesconnect is showing the updated build (1.5 & 1.6) under Activity > All Builds but page App store > Ready for sale still shows 1.4 under build. Also when on installation on the device from app store, users get the version 1.4, even after uninstalling and reinstalling the app

Comment: If it says that 1.4 is "Ready for sale", that means you haven't submitted any update to Apple yet. It's not enough to just upload a new binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you upload the build to appstore and it display on activity section, do this steps -

**1.** **Go to My Apps**

[image: My Apps]

---

**2.** **Select VERSION OR PLATFORM**

[image: Select VERSION OR PLATFORM]

---

**3.** **Then Select "iOS"**

[image: Select iOS]

---

**4.** **And now put your uploaded build number like 1.5 or 1.6**

[image: put your build number]

---

**5.** **After that is created click into that and now select the particular build version you uploaded like 1.5 or 1.6**

[image: select the build version]

---

**6.** **Last click on submit for review**

*.... and you are done :)*

Comment: Thanks for clarification :)